# react ajax axios not reaching symfony controller and returning template

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, symfony, templates

I'm trying to send some data via ajax in my react + symfony app.
There's no error but ajax is getting html template instead symfony function response. Here's the code:

Symfony 3.4 Controller Function :

```
/**
 * @Route("/loginPage", name="loginPage")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->request->get('username')){
        //make something curious, get some unbelieveable data
        $arrData = ['output' => 'here the result which will appear in div'];
        return new JsonResponse($arrData);
    }

    return new Response('success');

}
```

React component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Text } from 'react-form';
import axios from 'axios';


class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(setData, {
      username: this.state.name,
      password: this.state.password
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
  handleNameChange(e) {
  this.setState({name: e});
  }
  handlePasswordChange(e) {
    this.setState({password: e});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-block">
          <h4 className="card-title">Zaloguj się</h4>
          <div className="card-text">
            <Form>
              { formApi => (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="form1">
                  <Text className="form-control" field="name" id="name" placeholder="Login" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} required />
                  <Text className="form-control" field="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Hasło" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} required />
                  <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Zaloguj się</button>
                </form>
              )}
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login
```

And here is the response data im getting which is code of my twig template:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9WoH.png)

Please help :)

Comment: What is `setData` var in your `axios.post` ?

Comment: it's path '/loginPage'. Here is url from chrome network: 'http://localhost:8000/loginPage'

Comment: I suppose your symfony routing config/controllers are the issue.

Comment: it's my only thing in routing.yml: `app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation`

Comment: and controller file is int src/AppBundle/Controller

Comment: So if you run your react app with a webpack devserver you won't use the same port as your symfony server.

Comment: webpack dev server is on port 8080, i set symfony server to 8080 and send request on that port but response is still the same :(

Comment: You can't use the same port for both servers, you just have to change your request url to your symfony server ex: `axios.post('http://localhost:8000/loginPage', {...})`

Comment: now webpack server is on 8080, symfony server is 8000 and request is 8000 but problem is still the same

Comment: Can you try to do your request with a tool like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) ?

Comment: in postman it's the same, when i switch body to json it shows "unexpected '<'"

Comment: So there's something wrong in your symfony config, if i can give you an advice, if you are at the beginning of your project and not comfortable with symfony, you should give a try to a nodeJS server like express, the routing is easier to understand imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is adding route to routing.yml file in symfony, for example:

```
loginPage:
path:  /homePage
defaults: {
    _controller: AppBundle:Default:index,
    }
requirements:
    _method:  POST
```